# Vertical align property not working in ipad iOS 8

Tags: ios, css

vertical-align:middle property not working with ipad iOS version 8. It works on higher version of iOS

```
<span>Logo</span><span class="icon"></span>

.icon{
 font-size: 25px;
 display: inline;
 line-height: 0;
 vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: its *display: inline-block.

Comment: ya, i tried it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution to this bug: make the vertical-aligned element display: inline-block. It doesn't work for display: inline elements.